# Firebase User Favourites List

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Looking for a push in the right direction for creating a list of user favourites in Android. I have a list of items from a database which a user can scroll through and add to their favourites so when they log into their account they will be presented with a list of their favourite items. Is it possible to add an array or collection of some sort to the user so when they favourite an item then the primary id is added to some favourites parameter in their account which can be retrieved when they log in?

Sorry if this question is a bit basic, I am still new and am really only making this app to teach myself how to write android apps that use a database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a database. I would add a new table or column to your existing table that would be set to 'true' or 'false' depending on whether or not the item is a user favorite.

This is better than a [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) because if you store row IDs you now have to manage that information in two places.

Additionally it's easy to get all items or just favorited items using an SQL query.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So how would I make a table or database that is unique to the user? If that isn't possible with firebase then should I use a different platform? My app is only small so swapping to a different database won't pose any major issues.